# how to open composer in/for cpanel.?

Tags: magento2.3, composer

I am working on a magneto 2 site and everywhere I go there is written run this command and run that command but no explain how can I open that command line or composer. please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ubuntu os

You can either:

1. Open the Dash by clicking the Ubuntu icon in the upper-left, type "terminal", and select the Terminal application from the results that appear.
2. Hit the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Alt+T.

Then Navigate to your project

```
 cd /var/www/html/project_folder
```